# vim regex to replace if conditions

Tags: regex, vim

I try to replace something like:

`ch == 'q'` or `ch == "q"` with `ch == ord('q')`

I tried:

```
:%s/ch == [\'\"](.*)[\'\"]:/ch == ord('\1'):/gc
```

But it says pattern not found!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to escape `(` and `)` in the capturing group, you can avoid escaping `'` and `"` and should use non-greedy `.\{-}` (`:help non-greedy`) to match characters inside quotes. something like this:

```
:%s/ch == ['"]\(.\{-}\)['"]/ch == ord('\1')/g
```

Comment: You can also match the single/double quote and match it again. Also since we are using `ord` it is probably best to only match 1 character. e.g. `:%s/ch == \(['"]\)\(.\\)\1/ch == ord('\2')/g`

Comment: @PeterRincker if you match **only** 1 character inside quotes, then you wont be able to match characters like `'\n'`, `'\t'`, `'\u2020'` etc..

Comment: Very good point. Thank you. `:%s/ch == \(['"]\)\(.\{-}\\)\1/ch == ord('\2')/g`